# Javascript collsion detection

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new to this forum and new to JavaScript programming and I would like to know why my collision detection is not working. I would not like to use any library like JQuery, I just want it to work with pure JavaScript. Thank you for your help here is the code

```js
var can = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
var player1 = {x:"20", y:"20", w:"20", h:"20"};
var enemy1 = {x:"50", y:"50", w:"20", h:"20"};
ctx.fillRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
ctx.fillRect(enemy1.x,enemy1.y,enemy1.w,enemy1.h);
//right arrow moves block right
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
if(e.keyCode==39){
     ctx.clearRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
     player1.x++;
     ctx.fillRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
}});
//left arrow moves block left
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
if(e.keyCode==37){
     ctx.clearRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
     player1.x--;
     ctx.fillRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
}});
//up arrow makes block up
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
if(e.keyCode==38){
     ctx.clearRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
     player1.y--;
     ctx.fillRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
}});
//down arrow makes block go down
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
if(e.keyCode==40){
     ctx.clearRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
     player1.y++;
     ctx.fillRect(player1.x,player1.y,player1.w,player1.h);
}});

if(player1.x == enemy1.x && player1.y == enemy1.y){
alert("touch");
}
```

Comment: use a physics engine - https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js/. Sorry that doesn't *really* answer your question but why reinvent the wheel with tissue paper.

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i wanted to know. Also why would i need a physics engine?

Comment: Because it handles the logic of collision detection and all you need to worry about is rendering the view.

Comment: Reason for using a physics engine is it will give you code for doing collision detection and movement without having to write it yourself. If your goal is to make a game, it's probably worth using an engine. If your goal is just to learn how this stuff is made, then it is worth sticking it out and trying to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Micah, you should probably use an existing physics engine.

However the reason your collision detection code is not working is that it doesn't take into account the width and height of the enemy and player. At the moment it will only trigger when the player and enemy are COMPLETELY on top of each other (for example the pixel in the top left corner of each of them is touching).

What you need instead of `if (player1.x == enemy1.x && player1.y == enemy1.y)` is something like:
`if (player1.x + player1.w > enemy1.x &&
    player1.x < enemy1.x + enemy1.w &&
    player1.y + player1.h > enemy1.y && 
    player1.y < enemy1.y + enemy1.h)`

which checks if the player and the enemy are overlapping on any side.

Comment: Thanks Kazetsukai but what keeps happening is it when i move it over the enemy the enemy just disappears

Comment: That will be because you aren't redrawing the enemy every time you move the player, I suspect :)

Comment: thank you so much. also thanks for telling me why i would need a physics engine and yes my goal is to learn how this stuff is made, i just have had a lot of trouble with collision detection.